# dompdf special character converting into question mark

Tags: php, pdf, character-encoding, special-characters, dompdf

I have below html to parse with dompdf and generate a pdf file :-

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    td {
        margin-left: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        border: none;
    }

    table {
        border: none;
    }
    </style>


    <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: "nmsyms";
        src: url("customfonts/nmsyms.eot");
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: nmsyms;
        src: url(customfonts/NMSYMS__.TTF)
    }

    table {
        bgcolor: none
    }

    ;
    tr {
        bgcolor: none
    }

    ;
    td {
        bgcolor: none
    }
    ;
    </style></head><body><table align='center' width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0'
            cellpadding='2'>
            <tr>
                <th colspan=5 align='left' height=35>
                <h3>Temporary Corrections &nbsp;</h3>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan=5 align='left'><b>
                1569(T)/13&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; JAPAN - Hokkaidō West Coast. Kamui
                Misaki - Light.&nbsp;</b></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=4 align='left'>Source: <authority>Japanese
                Notice 11/5141(T)/13</authority>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align='left' colspan=4></td>
            </tr>
        </table></body></html>
```

You can see in second tr of above table `JAPAN - Hokkaidō West Coast. Kamui Misaki - Light.` . there is a special character `ō` . This character is converting into the question mark sign in generated pdf file but i dont want that. It should be as it is.

On webpage it's showing as it is.

Below is my php code using dompdf library : -

```
   $file= "files/2012_Week_40_info.html";
                 $NMtextpdfFile = 'nmtext.pdf';
                    $content = file_get_contents($file);
                    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
                $dompdf->load_html($content, 'UTF-8');

                $dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'portrait'); //portrait,landscape
                $dompdf->render();
                $output = $dompdf->output();
                file_put_contents($NMtextpdfFile, $output);
```

I have also some other special characters like accents but they are looking good in generated pdf

**I think this is font-family problem. Can any one tell me which font i have to apply to solve this problem ?**

Answer (score 0):

First, you have some syntax errors in your CSS. Semi-colons (;) should not be outside the curly braces. Semi-colons terminate individual declarations inside a style definition. So the following from your stylesheet is wrong:

```
table {
  bgcolor: none
}

;
tr {
  bgcolor: none
}
```

It should be something like:

```
table {
  bgcolor: none;
}

tr {
  bgcolor: none;
}
```

I'm not sure (I'd have to do some testing), but those misplaced semi-colons could be causing a parse error on the CSS.

Also, you appear to be attempting to include the "nmsyms" font using @font-face. But then you don't actually use it anywhere. To use a font (whether from your system or referenced using @font-face) you should apply it, e.g.

```
body { font-family: nmsyms; }
```

But for the character you want, the included DejaVu fonts (in dompdf 0.6.0) work just fine. So you could just as easily drop the @font-face and use the following:

```
body { font-family: "DejaVu Sans", sans; }
```